# For each loop doesn't work with multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a foreach loop with multiple variables through a multiple option panel. But when I input multiple variables it only inserts 1 variable somehow.

#### process.php:

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include 'connection.php';
function user_joined($user_werknemer,$user_project,$user_klant,$user_taak,$user_name,$user_desc, $user_start, $user_startdate, $user_starttime, $user_end, $user_enddate, $user_endtime, $user_color){

        $q = "INSERT INTO evenement (id,title,description,start,startdate,starttime,end,enddate,endtime,color) VALUES 
            ('','".$user_name."','".$user_desc."','".$user_start."','".$user_startdate."','".$user_starttime."','".$user_end."','".$user_enddate."','".$user_endtime."','".$user_color."') ";
            foreach ($user_werknemer as $test){
        $qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak) VALUES ('".$test."','".$user_project."',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$user_klant."','".$user_taak."')";
}

    mysql_query($q);
    
    mysql_query($qo);}
    
    
if(isset($_POST['user_werknemer'],$_POST['user_project'],$_POST['user_klant'],$_POST['user_taak'],$_POST['user_name'],$_POST['user_desc'],$_POST['user_startdate'],$_POST['user_start'],$_POST['user_starttime'],$_POST['user_enddate'],$_POST['user_endtime'],$_POST['user_end'],$_POST['user_color'],$_POST['action'])){
        
        $user_werknemer=$_POST['user_werknemer'];
        $user_color=$_POST['user_color'];
        $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
        $user_desc=$_POST['user_desc'];
        $user_project=$_POST['user_project'];
        $user_klant=$_POST['user_klant'];
        $user_taak=$_POST['user_taak'];
        $user_start=$_POST['user_startdate']." ".$_POST['user_starttime'];
        $user_startdate=$_POST['user_startdate'];
        $user_starttime=$_POST['user_starttime'];
        $user_end=$_POST['user_enddate']." ".$_POST['user_endtime'];
        $user_enddate=$_POST['user_enddate'];
        $user_endtime=$_POST['user_endtime'];
        $action=$_POST['action'];
        if ($action=='joined'){
            user_joined( $user_werknemer, $user_project, $user_klant, $user_taak, $user_name, $user_desc, $user_start, $user_startdate, $user_starttime, $user_end, $user_enddate, $user_endtime, $user_color);
            }
    }
/*if ( (isset($_POST["id"]) && strlen($_POST["id"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["id"]) <= 60) &&
    (isset($_POST["name"]) && strlen($_POST["name"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["name"]) <= 50) &&
    (isset($_POST["age"]) && strlen($_POST["age"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["age"]) <= 40) ) 
{   //check $_POST["name"] and $_POST["address"] and $_POST["city"] are not empty

    $id   = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age   = $_POST["age"];

    $q = "INSERT INTO tbltest ( id, name, age) VALUES 
            ('".$id."','".$name."','".$age."')";
    mysql_query($q); 

}*/
```

Comment: move this mysql_query($qo); inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is executed outside the foreach loop. Hence it is inserting only one value.

```
     foreach ($user_werknemer as $test){
        $qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak) VALUES ('".$test."','".$user_project."',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$user_klant."','".$user_taak."')";
 mysql_query($qo);
}
```

That should do...

Comment: i know whats wrong with it it only posts the last inserted id into the database. so in this case its posts the id of the last inserted row in the evenementontvanger table. I would like to get the auto-incremented id of the evenement table and post it into the evenementontvanger.idEvent column. But it wont work with the Last_insert_id() when i use multiple users.

Answer (score 2):

try your query execution in foreach loop you are calling query run outside foreach loop

```
 foreach ($user_werknemer as $test){
        $qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak) VALUES ('".$test."','".$user_project."',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$user_klant."','".$user_taak."')";


$execute_query = mysql_query($qo);
}
```

Try this it will insert data.